# Files edited outside the ide

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, ide, cvs

If I run a script to edit files outside of the ide I am using, will the ide recognize the changes made to the files?

More specifically:
-IDE: Netbeans 6.8
-Version Control: CVS
-OS: Windows XP

Comment: Why wouldn't it? After all, it's just a very fancy text editor.

Comment: I fail to see why you wouldn't just, you know, try it and find out.

Comment: I fail to see why posting the question here gives a quicker answer than just trying it out

Comment: In Eclipse you need to refresh (F5) the project to let the changes take effect in the deployment. Not sure if the same story applies to Netbeans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes. But the form designer of NetBeans considers some parts of the code "private", and you shouldn't modify these parts externally. They are identified by comments in the generated code:

```
* WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
* always regenerated by the Form Editor.
```

These parts are in fact generated from an external proprietary .form file, and having the source code not aligned with the .form code will mess everything up.

Comment: @ JB Nizet what is the difference between `java application` and `java desktop application` in netbeans?

Comment: So if there are no comments marking the code, editing the files outside the IDE should have no problems?
Thanks.

Comment: @Suhail Gupta A java application is a standared java app, whilst a java desktop application is based on the Swing Application Framework (JSR 296), which doesn't seem to be pursued any longer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it should. Give it a whirl and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with some caveats:

If you have those files open, edited, and unsaved in the IDE at the time, then you will need to tell the IDE whether to discard or keep your in-IDE changes.

If you have them open and unedited, then depending on the IDE, you may have to tell it to reload those files (the IDE should warn you that the file has changed since you last opened it).

If you move files around, and your IDE has some kind of project file (that tells it, among other things, where all the files are) and you don't update it accordingly, you may have problems.

Any files that you don't already have open in your IDE should behave as expected, and I would consider it a bug if it didn't pick up the changes.